# Get current fragment in Route, ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hash, routes

Is there away to get the current fragment from a route that was issued via action link. This is how I am getting the action from the route.

> string currentAction = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string ?? "index";

Can I do something similar to this?

> string currentFragment = requestContext.RouteData.Values["Fragment"] as string ?? "";

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by fragment?  Are you trying to get part of the URL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you can't do anything like this. The fragment (everything that follows the `#` sign in an url) is never sent to the server by the browser, so the sole fact of talking about getting the url fragment server side simply doesn't make sense.

So if you have the following url: `http://example.com/foo/bar?key1=value1#abc` the server will never be able to fetch `abc` simply because the client will never send it.

Comment: Could you please leave a comment when downvoting explaining why you think this answer is wrong?

Comment: That's what I thought. What if it is sent via Html.ActionLink?

Comment: @brenjt, no matter how it is sent. The server is never gonna get it. You could use an AJAX call which analyses the url and which replaces the part that follows the # sign with a normal query string parameter which the server could read. For example if you had `http://example.com/foo/bar?key1=value1#abc` you could have an AJAX call manipulate this url and replace it with `http://example.com/foo/bar?key1=value1&foo=abc` and then have your server use the `foo` query string parameter. But without javascript you are simply never gonna get anything that follows the `#` sign in an url on your server.

Answer (score 3):

As it has already been pointed out that is not possible. Document fragments (the string after the hash as you call it) are intended for the browsers only to correctly position the viewport. They have no meaning for the server and therefore are not transmitted there.

There is however a workaround you can use. Repeat the fragment as part of your url to make it accessible for the server.

Look at the permalink to the answers in this question. For instance, the link to my answer looks like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions
/6285833/get-current-fragment-in-route-asp-net-mvc/6286097#6286097
```

See how the value `6286097` is duplicated as the last route parameter. It's intentional. You can use this technique as well.

P.S. The fragment must point to an identifier in the document (id of some HTML element). At least in XHTML only identifiers work as fragments. Valid ids may not begin with a digit therefore instead of `#6286097` use something like `#answer-6286097`.

P.S.#2. Do not use any JavaScript trickery to get around this limitation. Basic site functionality and design must work without JavaScript - don't listen to anyone who tells you otherwise. Fragments obviously belong to the basic tool box. Use JavaScript only for advanced interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for you, but first of all lets get more into the problem.

The strings after the hash symbol which are called Fragment values are not query parameters but they are strings to be read by the client-side (living in the browser) and the server cannot read them because they are not sent to the server by the browser.

Some authentication providers like Google and Azure send the access token as Fragment value for security reasons so that they are not transferred over the internet after they get sent as direct response from the authentication provider.

The only way you can come around that is to use javascript to convert the fragment values to query parameters by replacing the '#' with '?' and redirecting to the endpoint in your server controller.

I suppose the easiest way is to handle all that from server, meaning you get get the request in server, send a javascript code to the browser on the fly, that replaces the '#' into '?' and redirects to your second endpoint which reads the token as strong parameter.

Here how you can do it in ASP.NET Core 3.1:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("authredirect")]
[Produces("text/html")]
public virtual ContentResult ConvertUrlFragmentToQueryParamThenRedirect()
{
  return Content("<html><script>window.location.href=window.location.href.replace('#', '?').replace('authredirect', 'authparams')</script></html>", "text/html");
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("authparams")]
public virtual void GetAccessToken([FromQuery] string access_token)
{
  // now you have your access token server side here
}
```

Please remember to set your redirectUrl to the correct one, in this case 'YOUR REDIRECT URL/authredirect'.