# How can I get #abc_xyz value in url http://localhost:4032/ShowResults/id#abc_xyz in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I know I can get url in mvc using

```
 request.url.query()
```

but # value is skipped can I find

```
#abc_xyz
```

value in url

```
 http://localhost:4032/ShowResults/id#abc_xyz
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Values after `#` sing are not passed to the server at all

Comment: For reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285833/get-current-fragment-in-route-asp-net-mvc  This also states that reading the `#` fragment is not possible server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some work must be done:

1. Each time on client side, when hash changes, you should store its value in hidden input.
2. If this ajax request, then you can store this value in request header or in data property, and on server side analize this data.
3. If this simple post request to action you can analize request form values for this value.